# Loop counter in for-loop (python) when writing in html template file

Tags: python, html, django

I need to use loop-counter in a pythonic for-loop in an html template file. How do I do it? Following is a piece of code that would provide a better idea of what I'm trying to say.

> {% for idx, keyword in enumerate(keywords) %}
>
> > ...do something with idx
>
> {% endfor %}

Here, 'keywords' is a list that I get through the Django dictionary. "Could not parse the remainder: '(keywords)' from 'enumerate(keywords)'" is what I get for the first line. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}

    {{ forloop.counter }} # 1 based
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} # 0 based

{% endfor %}
```

the documentation here has all the options that are available inside for loops

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 1):

To have the same index as in `enumerate`, use `forloop.counter0`. There is also `forloop.counter` for 1-based indexing.

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Check [forloop.counter0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for).